# UINavigationController pushViewController memory management

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, io, pushviewcontroller

I have a code like this:

```
MyViewController *myController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
[self.myNavController pushViewController:myController animated:YES];
[myController release];
```

In above case, deallc of MyViewController gets called twice resulting in a crash.
If I remove the last line "[myController release];" everything is fine.

Isn't this against the memory management guidelines?

Answer (score 0):

if i understand truly, you must use initWithNibName against init like below:

```
MyViewController *myController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
```

Please try this and reply, best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the MyViewController's dealloc method not release someObj more than once?
You can try to clear away dealloc content，then，run the app again.